# Помогите разобраться в коде после set:

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JS и в теме *Дескрипторы*, **геттеры и сеттеры** свойств столкнулся с примером кода, которого не понимаю Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что здесь и как происходит.

```js
'use stict'

var user = {
  name: "Ваcя",
  surname: "Петькин"
};

Object.defineProperty(user, "fullName", {
  get: function() {
    return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
  },

  set: function(value) {
    var split = value.split(' ');
    this.name = split[0];
    this.surname = split[1];
  }
});

user.fullName = "Петя Иванов"
alert(user.name);
alert(user.surname);
```

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, что именно вызывает у вас затруднения, какие части вы понимаете, а какие нет?

Comment: `user.fullName = "Петя Иванов"` попадает в set, разбивается в месте пробела на имя и фамилию и записывается. Еще не дописали в примере `alert(user.fullName);`, который попадет в get и выведет имя с фамилией

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var user = { // Объявляем переменную "user" и пишем в нее объект со следкюшими свойствами:
  name: "Ваcя", // "name" со значением "Вася",
  surname: "Петькин" // "surname" со значениеи "Петькин"
};

Object.defineProperty(user, "fullName", { // Определяем свойство "fullName" объекта "user".
  get: function() { // При обращении к свойству "fullName" выполнить следующий код:
    return this.name + ' ' + this.surname; // Вернуть строку, содержащую значения свойств "name" и "surname" объекта "user", разделенные пробелом.
  },

  set: function(value) { // При попытке изменить свойство "fullName" выполнить следующий код:
    var split = value.split(' '); // Новое строковое значение разбить на массив строк, используя в качестве разделителя пробел. Массив поместить в переменную "split".
    this.name = split[0]; // Значение свойства "name" объекта "user" изменить на значение элемента массива "split" с индексом 0.
    this.surname = split[1];  // Значение свойства "surname" объекта "user" изменить на значение элемента массива "split" с индексом 1.
  }
});

user.fullName = "Петя Иванов"
alert(user.name);
alert(user.surname);
```